# Converting an Arithmetic Series to Sigma Notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, time-series, geometric-series

I've been struggling with the following problem for quite a while now, and have been unable to identify a pattern;

> You have a geometric series $Y$ for which we have the following rule: 
>   $$Y_{t+1} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Y_t + \beta_2 Y_{t-1}.$$
>
> All beta variables ($\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_2$) are constants, while $Y_t$ and
>   $Y_{t-1}$ are the first and second lags of $Y_{t+1}$. Find an expression
>   for $Y_{t+h}$ as a function of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t-1}$ using finite sigma
>   notation.

If anyone can offer any advise about how I would go about solving it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I've tinkered with this problem for a little bit now. I'm really not sure where to start. Of course its possible to just solve the recurrence explicitly using standard methods (Mathematica will do this for you), but I can't find a way to express $Y_{t + h}$ compactly as a sum in terms of $Y_t$ and $Y_{t-1}$. I looked at $Y_{t + h}$ for $1 \leq h \leq 5$ and couldn't find a pattern.